# Jupyter Notebook slideshow offline

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a few IPython Notebooks which I need to convert to slides and render. Currently I am using the command `jupyter-nbconvert slides.ipynb --to slides --post serve` and it renders the notebook slides using the reveal.js from the CDN. However, when I tried using a local copy of reveal.js, I am getting just a blank page or plain HTML as output instead of a slideshow. I would like to know how I can achieve the rendering of the slideshow offline.

The IPython version I'm using is 4.2.0 and Jupyter version is 4.1.0. I have installed them both using conda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using nbconvert, you can simply use [damianavila's](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE) extension for Jupyter Notebook based on [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/)

The documentation is pretty good as well as the project is alive.

This should solve your issue